# Using SmartPointer as result data type in function requires invoke call explicitly

Tags: delphi, smart-pointers

I am using the SmartPointer in http://members.adug.org.au/2011/12/05/smart-pointers/

I defined a IStringList:

```
type
  IStringList = ISmartPtr<TStringList>;
```

I may then use as follow without memory leak prompt:

```
var S: IStringList;
begin
  S := TSmartPtr<TStringList>.Create();
  S.Add('abc');
end;
```

If I use the IStringList as result data type in a function:

```
function GetList: IStringList;
begin
  Result := TSmartPtr<TStringList>.Create();
  Result.Add('abc');   // E2010
end;
```

I get a compiler error:

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(31): E2010 Incompatible types: 'SmartPointer.ISmartPtr<System.Classes.TStringList>' and 'Procedure of object'
```

A workaround solution would be:

```
  Result.Invoke.Add('abc');
```

But that defeat the purpose of syntax cleanliness of using SmartPointer.  Is there a solution?

Comment: I'd say the smart pointer does more harm than good. To my eyes it makes the code less clear.

Comment: @TOndrej Not here it does not. Try the SSCCE in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: What is SSCCE?

Comment: Google knows the answer to that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've noticed the difference when you omit the brackets  in the constructor call (`.Create;` vs. `.Create();`), too; however, the OP's code does include the brackets and it does compile.

Comment: @TOndrej it's the Result.Add line that counts. Code in the Q compiles on no extant Delphi versions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan My mistake, you're right. The difference was in using a local variable vs. using Result, as you correctly stated in your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite an interesting one. For whatever reason, the compiler treats `Result` differently from other variables. I see no good reason for that, so this feels like a compiler bug.

I see a few workarounds:

1. Declare a local variable, use that, and finish the function by assigning that local variable to `Result`.
2. Using parens to call the function: `Result().Add('abc')`.
3. Using a better smart pointer. For instance, a smart pointer that is not based on method invocation would be a good start. A generic record with an implicit conversion operator would presumably work.
4. Find a version of the compiler without the bug, if indeed it is a compiler bug.
5. Give up on smart pointers and write traditional style code. Every time I contemplate using smart pointers in Delphi I conclude that I'd rather see the explicit try/finally blocks and understand when my objects are created and destroyed.

---

FWIW, you can greatly simplify the issue by stripping out the smart pointer code, and removing the generic types. Here is the cleanest SSCCE that I can concoct:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TFunc = reference to function: TObject;

procedure Foo;
var
  F: TFunc;
begin
  F.ClassName; // compiles
end;

function Bar: TFunc;
begin
  Result().ClassName; // compiles
  Result.ClassName; // [dcc32 Error] E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ClassName'
end;

begin
end.
```

I'm now convinced that this is a compiler bug.

It is presumably related to the rather unusual language feature of Delphi that means the function call parentheses can be omitted for a function that has no parameters. This convenience sometimes brings with it ambiguity. However, in this case there is no ambiguity. The `.` operator has no meaning when applied to a `TFunc<TObject>` and so the only way to interpret these statements is that the function is called, and the `.` operator applied to the returned value.

Bug report: [QC123218](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=123218).

Comment: Invoke `Result().ClassName` in `function Bar` works but invoke `Bar().ClassName` in other places will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ I'm not allowed to comment... -.-' Feel free making it one. }
```

I'm afraid there is no way without defeating the purpose of smart pointers. I tried to solve your problem as part of trying to find a way to [assign an anonymous method to an interface variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533381/assign-an-anonymous-method-to-an-interface-variable-or-parameter) (SO question from July 2013). Coming back to it every now and then or asking around didn't help in finding a solution.