# How can assignment of function references be unit tested?

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, reference, equality

Imagine I have a class like this:

```
type TFunctionWrapper<T1,T2> = class
private
  FFunc : TFunc<T1,T2>;
public
  constructor Create(AFunc : TFunc<T1,T2>);
  function Apply(AValue : T1) : T2;
end;
```

with implementation

```
constructor TFunctionWrapper<T1,T2>.Create(AFunc : TFunc<T1,T2>);
begin
  FFunc := AFunc;
end;

function TFunctionWrapper<T1,T2>.Apply(AValue : T1) : T2;
begin
  Result := FFunc(AValue);
end;
```

How can i test, if the assigned functions are the same? Function references cannot be equated with `F1 = F2` as it result in a compiler error:

`[dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(37): E2035 Not enough actual parameters`,

which makes pretty good sense.

Anyway, the problem remains: *How do you test if assigning a function to a field work as intended, without just testing if the field and the function return the same result on the same input?*

Answer (score 0):

These are reference method types, declared with `reference to`. They are implemented as interfaces, automatically created and managed by the compiler.

So, you can test for equality by casting to an interface, and using interface equality:

```
IInterface(Pointer(@F1)^) = IInterface(Pointer(@F2)^)
```

This is a little bit gnarly, and thanks to Stefan Glienke's answer here for showing me how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645248/505088

But be warned that this might not give the results that you expect. For instance this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

function Foo(Value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := Value;
end;

var
  F1, F2: TFunc<Integer, Integer>;

begin
  F1 := Foo;
  F2 := Foo;
  Writeln(IInterface(Pointer(@F1)^) = IInterface(Pointer(@F2)^));
  Readln;
end.
```

outputs `FALSE`. That's because the compiler creates two distinct anonymous methods for `F1` and `F2`. The compiler could, in theory, detect that both anonymous methods call the same function, in the same context, and optimise this code to use the a single anonymous method. But the compiler does not do that.